# glmer: how to test intra-patient variability to point out a clustering effect in drug concentration-outcome study

Tags: lme4-nlme

It is still not clear to me how to test for intra-patient variability test in R, and I wish to receive some help again.

I have some subjects and each of them has been measured for drug concentration (continuous variable, repeated measurements) and outcome (binary variable Y/N, repeated measurements). Concentration and outcome data vary within an individual on different days. I hypothesize that there is a drug concentration-outcome relationship. I would like to test the effect of intra-patient drug concentration variability on the outcome. My model is:

```
model1 <- glmer(outcome ~ drug_concen + (drug_concen | patient ID), family = binomial(), data = data1)
```

It was suggested to me to test for the clustering effect (whether intra-patient variability is zero) via a likelihood ratio test, or compare the AIC values. But I am wondering if my control model should be as follows:

```
model2 <- glm(outcome ~ drug_concen, family = binomial(), data = data1)
anova(model1, model2)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to test whether the `outcome` measurements are correlated within patients (i.e., intra-patient variability), then indeed you can use the likelihood ratio test between the two models you have provided.

More specifically, the model that allows for correlations and is fitted by `glmer()` is $$\log\left(\frac{\pi_{ij}}{1 - \pi_{ij}}\right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \texttt{drug_conc}_{ij} + b_{i0} + b_{i1} \texttt{drug_conc}_{ij},$$ where $\pi_{ij} = \mbox{Pr}(Y_{ij} = 1 \mid b_i)$, with $Y_{ij}$ denoting the dichotomous outcome of subject $i$ at time $j$, and $$b_i = \left [\begin{array}{c}b_{i0}\\ b_{i1}\end{array} \right] \sim \mathcal N \left (0, \left[\begin{array}{cc} \sigma_0^2 & \sigma_{01}\\ \sigma_{01} & \sigma_1^2\end{array} \right]\right),$$ where $\sigma_0^2$ is the variance for the random intercepts, $\sigma_1^2$ is the variance for the random slopes, and $\sigma_{01}$ the covariance between the random intercepts and slopes. Then, the specific null hypothesis you're testing by comparing the two models is: $$H_0: \sigma_0^2 = \sigma_1^2 = \sigma_{01} = 0.$$

As an additional point, you may also want to consider including the time effect in the model.